# Como listar todos os dias entre duas datas para mais de um registro (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Apliquei uma orientação de outro tópico e funcionou legal quando se tem apenas um registro na tabela com o intervalo, porém tive problemas quando o mesmo registro tem mais de um intervalo de datas.

Utilizando a query abaixo:

```
select trunc(to_date(X.DT_ENTRADA)) + (level-1) periodo
  from dual
connect BY level <= to_number(to_date(X.DT_SAIDA) - TO_DATE(X.DT_ENTRADA)) + 1
```

e tendo a tabela "ENTRADAS" abaixo como exemplo:

```
ID  DT_ENTRADA   DT_SAIDA     CD_PESSOA   
1   01/01/2018   05/01/2018   123        
2   03/01/2018   07/01/2018   123  
3   10/03/2018   15/03/2018   999        
4   15/03/2018   17/03/2018   999
```

Como eu montaria uma lista única contendo todos os dias entre estes intervalos agrupado por pessoa? Ou seja:

```
PERIODO      ID   CD_PESSOA  
01/01/2018   1    123   
02/01/2018   1    123   
03/01/2018   1    123   
03/01/2018   2    123   
04/01/2018   1    123   
04/01/2018   2    123   
05/01/2018   1    123   
05/01/2018   2    123   
06/01/2018   2    123   
07/01/2018   2    123
```

Se tiver uma maneira de montar a lista contendo somente os distintos melhor ainda, do contrario pretendo usar o bom e velho `DISTINCT` nas datas da lista.

Tentei adaptar da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT DISTINCT trunc(to_date(X.DT_ENTRADA) + (LEVEL - 1),
        X.ID
  FROM (
        SELECT Y.ID,
               Y.DT_ENTRADA,
               Y.DT_SAIDA,
               Y.CD_PESSOA
          FROM ENTRADAS Y
         WHERE Y.CD_PESSOA = 123
       ) X
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_number(to_date(X.DT_SAIDA) - TO_DATE(X.DT_ENTRADA)) + 1
```

mas não rolou. O resultado vem na mesma proporção de uma Progressão Geométrica (1,2,4,8,16...), ou seja,neste exemplo vai retornar:
1x `01/01/2018`, 2x `02/01/2018`, 4x `03/01/2018`, 8x `04/01/2018` e 16x `05/01/2018` para o `ID 1` e
1x `03/01/2018`, 2x `04/01/2018`, 4x `05/01/2018`, 8x `06/01/2018` e 16x `07/01/2018` para o `ID 2`.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: e se tiver um registro assim: `5   02/01/2018   06/01/2018   111` ?

Comment: como esse registro vai ser único para a pessoa `111`, então a primeira query vai retornar a lista correta abaixo:

    `02/01/2018`   
    `03/01/2018`   
    `04/01/2018`   
    `05/01/2018`   
    `06/01/2018`

Comment: ps. Sempre será filtrado por apenas um `CD_Pessoa` ?

Comment: Sim, a pergunta que pretendo responder é: Quanto tempo a pessoa ficou no local em determinado intervalo de tempo? com base nas datas de entrada e saída.
Esta tabela é simples, mas tenho que considerar vários registros pra mesma pessoa em vários intervalos de tempo que muitas vezes não tem intersecção, por exemplo, entra dia 01 sai dia 05 depois entra de novo 10 e sai dia 15. Temos que pegar somente os dias do intervalo onde a pessoa ficou no local.

Comment: não tinha entendido essa parte da interseção das datas, mas acho que é mais fácil de resolver

Comment: mais um detalhe: você precisa apenas dos intervalos que tem interseção ?!

Comment: Não eu preciso justamente o contrário. Seguindo o exemplo do comentário anterior, deveria me retornar os dias `01 02 03 04 05 10 11 12 13 14 15`. Se tivesse entrado 01, saído 05, depois entrado novamente dia 05 e saído dia 07 deveria trazer `01 02 03 04 05 05 06 07`. Ou melhor ainda se fosse `01 02 03 04 05 06 07` sem o `05` repetido.

Comment: Não é o que está no segundo código que postei?

Comment: Pois é, estou analisando as respostas e convertendo aqui pra ver se vai rolar. Posto em breve o resultado

Answer (score 2):

Atualização:

Devida explicação adicional, onde a necessidade seria determinar o tempo que a pessoa ficou no local, fiz o seguinte comando:

```
with 
dias as 
(
  select (e.x + level -1)  dia
  from (select min(a.dt_entrada) x, max(a.dt_saida) y from entradas a where a.cd_pessoa = 123) e
  connect by level <= ceil(y-x)+1
), xentradas as 
(select 
d.dia,
(select LISTAGG(x.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.id) as ids from entradas x 
 where x.cd_pessoa = e.cd_pessoa 
 and (x.dt_entrada >= e.dt_entrada and x.dt_entrada <= e.dt_saida
     OR x.dt_saida >= e.dt_entrada and x.dt_saida <= e.dt_saida )) as ids_entradas,
e.cd_pessoa     
from dias d
inner join entradas e on d.dia between e.dt_entrada and e.dt_saida
)

select 
min(x.dia),
max(x.dia),
max(x.dia)- min(x.dia) as duracao_dias,
x.ids_entradas,
x.cd_pessoa
from xentradas x
group by x.ids_entradas, x.cd_pessoa;
```

> Resultado:

```
MIN(X.DIA)              MAX(X.DIA)              DURACAO_DIAS    IDS_ENTRADAS    CD_PESSOA
2018-01-10T00:00:00Z    2018-01-15T00:00:00Z    5               5         123
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z    2018-01-07T00:00:00Z    6               1,2       123
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd8db/50)

---

Se ainda precisar do resultado, listando todos os registros,  como no seu exemplo:

```
with 
dias as 
(
  select (e.x + level -1)  dia
  from (select min(a.dt_entrada) x, max(a.dt_saida) y from entradas a where a.cd_pessoa = 123) e
  connect by level <= ceil(y-x)+1
)

select 
d.dia,
x.id,
e.cd_pessoa     
from dias d
inner join entradas e on d.dia between e.dt_entrada and e.dt_saida
left outer join entradas x on x.cd_pessoa = e.cd_pessoa 
 and (x.dt_entrada >= e.dt_entrada and x.dt_entrada <= e.dt_saida
 and x.dt_saida >= e.dt_entrada and x.dt_saida <= e.dt_saida )
order by d.dia
```

> Resultado:

```
DIA                     ID  CD_PESSOA
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-02T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-03T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-03T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-04T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-04T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-05T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-05T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-06T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-07T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-10T00:00:00Z    5   123
2018-01-11T00:00:00Z    5   123
2018-01-12T00:00:00Z    5   123
2018-01-13T00:00:00Z    5   123
2018-01-14T00:00:00Z    5   123
2018-01-15T00:00:00Z    5   123
```

ps. Adicionei um ID 5, para considerar o exemplo do comentário.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd8db/54)

Após isso, acredito que basta você filtrar pela data do período que deseja consultar

---

Fiz o seguinte:

Selecionei todo o intervalo que tem na tabela com um `UNION`, e coloquei em uma tabela temporária chamada `datas`. Assim fica mais fácil de conseguir a maior e a menor data.

Depois, gerei uma sequencia de números, contando a diferença de dias entre a menor e a maior data. Guardei essa sequencia em uma tabela temporária chamada `serie`.

Por fim, Selecionei a menor data do intervalo, somando a sequencia numérica, tendo assim uma lista com todos os dias dentro do intervalo.

Agora, basta fazer o `Select` com os dados da tabela. Segue o código:

```
with datas as 
(
  select dt_entrada as data from entradas
  union 
  select dt_saida from entradas
), serie as 
(
  select level l
  from dual
   connect by level <= ceil(((select max(data) from datas)-(select min(data) from datas)))+1
), dias as 
(
  select 
    ((select min(data) from datas) +l-1) as dia
  from serie
)

select
d.dia,
e.id,
e.cd_pessoa
from entradas e 
left outer join dias d on d.dia >= e.dt_entrada and d.dia <= e.dt_saida   
where e.cd_pessoa = 123
order by d.dia
```

> Resultado:

```
DIA                     ID  CD_PESSOA
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-02T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-03T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-03T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-04T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-04T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-05T00:00:00Z    1   123
2018-01-05T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-06T00:00:00Z    2   123
2018-01-07T00:00:00Z    2   123
```

**Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53dc81/29)**

Comment: Analisando a query e levando os dados mais próximos da realidade aqui, parece que ele se perdeu nessa lógica. Coloquei as alterações  no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02991/1)

Comment: veja isso: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02991/9

Comment: Cara, engraçado que eu estou executando a mesma lógica, até com os nomes dos campos bem próximos aos que usamos no exemplo e ele não está respeitando o código do atendimento. pra pegar a menor e maior data ele respeita, mas aí usa a maior e menor data desse atendimento pra aplicar a regra para todos os outros atendimentos da tabela, acredito que o problema esteja na query seguinte ao connect by, mas não vejo diferença comparando com a query do exemplo... vou continuar analisando e retorno com mais informações.

Comment: certo, se puder esclarecer o que precisa: `tempo de permanencia por atendimento` ou `tempo de permanencia por sequencia` ou `maior intervalo de permanencia` acho que ainda não está muito claro pra mim

Comment: Imagina uma tabela populada com milhões de registros, o único filtro que irei passar é **setor** e **data**. O retorno do relatório vai ser por `Atendimento`, ou seja, `o tempo de permanência por atendimento`. Este seu SQL no exemplo se comporta como eu preciso pra agregar no restante da query, mas na minha base não está se comportando da mesma forma.