# Desdobrar as linhas num intervalo de datas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma questão em relação ao SQL SERVER e precisava da vossa ajuda. Tenho uma Query que me devolve uma linha com um numero, Data_inicio e Data_fim.

**Consulta:**

```
select 123456 as Numero, a.Data_inicio, a.Data_fim
from CLI_INTERNAMENTOS_UTENTES a
where a.Data_inicio between '20171001' and '20180601'
```

**Resultado:**

> ```
> Numero    Data_inicio Data_fim
> 123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018
> ```

Pretendia mostrar um registo por cada dia até o último ser igual data_fim, ou seja:

```
Numero  Data_inicio Data_fim    Data(novo campo)
1.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  01/10/2017
2.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  02/10/2017
3.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  03/10/2017
4.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  04/10/2017
5.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  05/10/2017
6.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  06/10/2017
7.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  07/10/2017
8.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  08/10/2017
9.123456    01/10/2017  01/06/2018  09/10/2017
10.123456   01/10/2017  01/06/2018  10/10/2017
11.123456   01/10/2017  01/06/2018  11/10/2017
12.123456   01/10/2017  01/06/2018  12/10/2017
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de cada coluna? no seu select você está tratanto a data como string. Como ela foi armazenada?

Comment: O tipo de data e datetime, mas posso fazer um cast para date.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33860/69359

Comment: É quase a mesma situação que essa questão, mas esta usa oracle: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299572/69359

Comment: Para cada valor da coluna Numero existe uma única linha na tabela CLI_INTERNAMENTOS_UTENTES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH q (data_inicio, data_fim, data) AS
( 
    SELECT a.data_inicio, a.data_fim, a.data_inicio AS data
    FROM CLI_INTERNAMENTOS_UTENTES a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.data_inicio, a.data_fim, DATEADD(day, 1, q.data)
    FROM CLI_INTERNAMENTOS_UTENTES a
    INNER JOIN q ON q.data_inicio = a.data_inicio AND q.data_fim = a.data_fim
    WHERE a.data_fim > q.data
) 
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data ASC) AS varchar) + '.123456' AS Numero, data_inicio, data_fim, data
FROM q
WHERE data_inicio BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2018-06-01'
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, acho que é o que preciso. Vou testar e depois dou um feedback.

Comment: Favor marcar como resposta, caso o código seja-lhe útil.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Sugestão: gere a numeração sequencial na própria CTE recursiva; isto evita a necessidade do row_number() posterior, que provavelmente força a uma ordenação interna (operador SORT).

Comment: https://snag.gy/Zp5SRn.jpg